# Shell compare number

Tags: shell

I'm trying to compare 2 numbers, What is wrong in the below code?

```
    filesize=$(stat -c '%s' ${FILENAME})

    if [ $filesize -gt 12  ] ; then
        echo "Yes bigger ";
    fi
```

I'm not getting any error but I never get "Yes bigger" printed.

Comment: what is the error message...?

Comment: Works well for me. Which shell you are using?

Comment: Works for me (RHEL6.1, /bin/bash). Maybe your first command does not what you expect. Is $FILENAME set properly? Maybe $filesize is <= 12?

Comment: Got it working I was echoing "filesize=$(stat -c '%s' ${FILENAME})" before use.

Comment: At times like this checking the weird can make sense. echo /$filesize/ to be sure your numbers are pure and space free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. I was echoing "filesize" before compare.

```
filesize=$(stat -c '%s' ${FILENAME})

if [ $filesize -gt '12'  ] ; then
    echo "Yes bigger ";
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, this would have told you what's the matter:

```
filesize=$(stat -c '%s' ${FILENAME})

if [ $filesize -gt 12 ]
then
    echo "bigger"
elif [ $filesize -lt 12 ]
then
    echo "smaller"
else
    echo "equal"
fi
```

And: It might come a case where it is important **which** shell you are using. So it might be helpful to have this information in your question.